# Customize the winrar context menu handler in Windows explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

How to Customize the winrar context menu handler in Windows explorer to only show "Add to rar" item ?

[image]

ShellEx only shows Winrar:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the option for customization
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem using rar.exe (the command line utility) that is included in WinRAR.
I created this reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RarMe]
@="Rar With Pass"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RarMe\command]
@="\"C:\\rar\\rar.exe\" a -hptest -m0 -ep1 -r -v350000 -y \"%1\" \"%1\\*.*\""
```

This creates a menù that when you click on a directory and execute the command.
In my example I clicked on a folder and created a RAR file with the name of the folder with password "test" compression "store" recursive folders and split at 350000k without prompt.

You can modify the options to suit your individual needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think WinRAR has an option in the settings menu. However if you uninstall it and install it again, it will let you choose the context menu you specifically want in the context menu as shown here:

[image]

Comment: correct..customization is possible through the winrar program settings..check my own answer

Answer (score 0):

These context menu options are specified in the registry. There's a free tool called [Shell Menu View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) that you can use to edit these in a user-friendly way. Just find the options you don't want (the leftmost column in the Shell Menu View window lists the options as they appear in the menu) and click the red toolbar button to disable them. They may be listed multiple times for different file types.

Comment: ShellEx only shows one entry for Winrar

Comment: Check for it being inserted in a different location. Sometimes they're 'hidden'

Comment: not sure, since the customization is possible through the winrar program settings..check my own answer