# WinRar - Custom shell commands

Tags: command-line, shell, context-menu, winrar

i'm trying to create custom commands on the context menu in windows.

i found this great registry hack here: https://superuser.com/a/376879/395548

this is the code made to work for me:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RarMe]
    @="Rar Here"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RarMe\command]
    @="\"C:\\Winrar\\Winrar.exe\" a -cpSuperExe -ep1 -r -y \"%1\" \"%1\\*.*\""
```

this works beautifully but not for files, only for folders.

whatever syntax editing i try, on files i get nothing - or errors.

(it's such a clean solution!)

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 0):

<s>The problem lies in the location of the key you created - you'll notice that it's located in "Directory"? This means that the addition will apply to directories (folders).</s>

If you add the same stuff to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\..., it should work for all files.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RarMe]
@="Rar Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\RarMe\command]
@="\"C:\\Winrar\\Winrar.exe\" a -cpSuperExe -ep1 -y \"%1\" \"%1\""
```

This should do it, though you might need to add an extension to the archive name (the first \"%1\").

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, i already tried, did it on '*'.   but no results.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Might be worth adding that to your question.

Comment: Thanks. Just to check-  do you get the entry added to the context menu, and then it silently fails, or is it not adding the option?

Comment: yes, the menu is fine, on running you will only see a prompt flash.  nothing else.

Comment: Are you selecting a single file, or multiple? Just looking at the last line, looks like you might be trying to select all files within the "file" (trying as a folder). But just checking what the last portion of the command is doing (\"%1\\*.*\").

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I don't have a copy of WinRar installed here, but the changes made to the answer should help.

Comment: ideally any number of files.   a lot of the complex stuff can be handled by winrar profiles (ie, rar each file individually), so i though just pointing the file to that profile command would be enough.